# Cannot upload images to Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, polymer, firebase-storage

First I initialized a Polymer app-drawer-template using the Polymer cli and then I added Firebase storage to the web app. Then I added file upload code to one of the pages (The code for the page is found below). However I am getting the following errors (This prevents files from being uploaded and also does not update the progress bar),

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

and also

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'instanceCount' of undefined

This is my code.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="my-market">

  <template>

    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      paper-card.top{
        margin-top: 8px;
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 16px;
      }
    </style>

    <paper-card heading="Welcome to the Market!">
      <div class="card-content">
        <h4>Upload a photo of your item</h4>
        <!--uplod image-->
        <input type="file" value="upload" id="fileUpload"/>
        <progress value="0" max="100" id="uploader">0%</progress>
      </div>
    </paper-card>

  </template>

  <script>

   //File upload script to Firebase storage
  var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
  var fileButton = document.getElementById('fileUpload');

  //File selection listener
  fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(a) {

    //Get image
    var file = a.target.files[0];

    //create a storage reference
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('images/' + file.name);

    //store the image
    var task = storageRef.put(file);

    //notify the user of upload status
    task.on('state_changed',

        function progress(snapshot) {
          var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred/snapshot.totalBytes)*100;
          uploader.value = percentage;
        },

        function error(err) {

        },

        function complete() {

        }

    );

  });

  </script>


  <script>

    Polymer({

      is: 'my-market'

    });

  </script>

</dom-module>
```

I also tried to place the code for Firebase Storage in the  tag of the index.html file but it's still not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the fix.

Just put your script inside the Polymer({}); function.

```
Polymer({

  is: 'my-market',

  upld: function(a) {
      //Get image
     var file = a.target.files[0];

     //create a storage reference
     var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('images/' + file.name);

     //store the image
     var task = storageRef.put(file);

 }

});
```

And specify the on-change attribute to "upld" for the file input.

Comment: Yes... Any ideas why?

Comment: I just have a look on this template's doc , it seems like you should delegate
your custom event by following its rule , define your event
within js-object that give to Polymer({..here...});
have a look on its offical doc
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events
and notice at the 'Custom events' part

Comment: or just have a quick try , move your <script>-image process-</script>
out of the <dom-module></dom-module>  tag
,above link's 'Event retargeting' part have an example code like this behavior

Comment: Thanks for the help, just looked at the documentation and solved it.